# how to display the date and time from rss feed in iphone

Tags: objective-c

I am getting data from the rss feeder. The data contains title, description and date & time.

I'm getting the date as "Thu, 21 Apr 2011 14:23:41 +0100" from rss feeder. I wanted to remove +0100 from the date and display it. Can any one help me out with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to take another approach. Use a NSDateFormatter to parse this date, and output it with another formatter. As you might know there are people living in non-english countries, and most likely they like their dates formatted in their local style.
And if the reader of the feed is in a different timezone than the server (or the author?) the time will be wrong anyway.

Something like this will display the actual date and time in the local format. I would recommend to use something similar.

```
NSString *str = @"Thu, 21 Apr 2011 14:23:41 +0100";

NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[inputFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease]];
[inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"];

NSDate *date = [inputFormatter dateFromString:str];

NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[outputFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
[outputFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
NSString *outStr = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: It's not necessary create NSDateFormatter and all this stuff if you just want to cut the end of the string. Do you agree?

Comment: I don't agree, for the reason mentioned in the first paragraph. Removing a timezone offset changes the time. And people outside of english speaking countries will say "Thu? What the f does this mean?"

Comment: Malathi didn't tell anything about time correction. He wants only "remove" and "display". There is no need to solve not-existing problems

Comment: Sometimes people don't know what they should do, so I offered an alternative to the wrong way of removing the timezone. And actually it's not time correction, it's keeping the correct time. There is a reason the timezone exists in this timestamp. But feel free to downvote my answer.

Comment: No, I don't want to vote down your answer, it's absolutely correct. I just wanted to see alternative to mine opinion. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here how you can do that

```
NSString * str = @"Thu, 21 Apr 2011 14:23:41 +0100";
[str substringToIndex:[str length] - 6];
```

why [str length] - 6] because the length of " +0100" is 6.

Good Luck !

Comment: I've delete my "copy" of your answer) But you should agree, that -6, but not -5 :)